# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: e - simple e.preventDefault() function

Tags: javascript

I'm surprised this error is occurring but I do not actually know how to fix it. To summarise, I'm getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: e
```

But the event object should be found, as it is being passed into the function... So why is it not being found? I assume I'm doing something pretty daft here.

```css
a {
  font-size: 2em;
}
a:after {
  content: 'a';
}
div.show a:after {
  content: 'b';
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
  <a onclick='testToggle(e)'></a>
</div>
<script>
  const el = document.querySelector('.test');

  const testToggle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    el.classList.toggle('show');
  }
</script>
```

I can of course just remove the `preventDefault` and `e` variable, but I need the `preventDefault` behaviour to stop the dom from scrolling after clicking the link.

Can someone advise where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: What browser are you using

Comment: Don’t pass anything to the onclick

Comment: ☝️What he said. In the `onclick` call, use the function name as a reference rather than calling it with a parameter. I. E. `onclick=“testToggle”` without the parentheses.

Comment: Also, consider using a `button` element instead of `a` in this context.

Comment: Maybe yout element .test is not available when your script is running. Try without caching it into a variable but just querySelector it in function only when needed. If it works, i was true

Comment: It's not because it's in your source code it's available in DOM

Comment: Almost all the comments are wrong. `onclick='testToggle()'` will cause `e` to be undefined. `onclick='testToggle'` doesn’t do anything. `“` and `”` are generally not used in programming; `onclick=“testToggle”` will be parsed as `onclick="“testToggle”"`, causing a syntax error. The error message has nothing to do with the DOM not being loaded.

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Please _never_ suggest or encourage these attributes. The last browser that still needs them reached end of life nearly two decades ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid inline JS listeners and use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.test');
el.addEventListener('click', testToggle, false);

function testToggle(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  el.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
a { font-size: 2em; }
a:hover { cursor: pointer; }
a:after { content: 'a'; }
div.show a:after { content: 'b'; color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <a href="http://google.com"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

do it like this :

HTML

```
<div class='test'>
  <a id="toggle">test</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
const el = document.querySelector('.test');
const toggle = document.getElementById("toggle")
toggle.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  el.classList.toggle('show');
})
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//html 
<div class='test'>
    <a></a>
</div>
//js you can use event listener to have the click event 
<script>
    const el = document.querySelector('.test');
    const link= document.querySelector('.test a');

    link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        el.classList.toggle('show')
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using `e` in the onclick property, use `event`.

```html
<div class='test'>
  <a onclick='testToggle(event)'></a>
</div>

<script>
  const el = document.querySelector('.test');

  const testToggle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    el.classList.toggle('show');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event